# Compare the names of vectors and select the common ones and sum the values

Tags: r, vector

I am trying to finding the common names among three vectors with names. I want to find the common names among these three vectors and count(or sum) the values of these common named vectors.

For example:

```
vec1<- c(1:20)
names(vec1) = c( "X13" , "X25", "X58", "X79", "X95" , "X118", "X212", "X311",    
            "X422" , "X536", "X899", "X1005","X1080" , "X1118", "X1322", "X1516","X1705" 
            , "X1890", "X1925", "X2008")
vec2<- c(21:40)
names(vec2) = c( "X11" , "X25", "X58", "X79", "X119" , "X120", "X212", "X311",    
            "X422" , "X536", "X899", "X995","X1080" , "X1098", "X1322", "X1516","X1705" 
            , "X1890", "X1930", "X2008")

vec3<- c(41:60)
names(vec3) = c( "X13" , "X25", "X58", "X79", "X95" , "X118", "X212", "X311",    
            "X422" , "X536", "X899", "X1005","X1080" , "X1118", "X1322", "X1516","X1705" 
            , "X1890", "X1925", "X2010")
```

In the above example, In vec1, vec2, and vec3 the "x25" is the common name with the value 2,22 and 42. So the output should have x25 with the value as 66 (2+22+42=66).

Also, "x13" is present in vec1 and vec3 but is not present in vec2. So it should be ignored.

I tried using is.equal but i am getting errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `Reduce` along with `intersect` to find out the common names between all the vectors and then subset those from all the vectors and add them.

```
common_names <- Reduce(intersect, list(names(vec1), names(vec2), names(vec3)))

vec1[common_names] + vec2[common_names] + vec3[common_names]    

#  X25   X58   X79  X212  X311  X422  X536  X899 X1080 X1322 X1516 X1705 X1890 
#   66    69    72    81    84    87    90    93    99   105   108   111   114
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
list(vec1, vec2, vec3) %>% 
   map_df(enframe, .id = 'vec') %>% 
   group_by(name) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(vec) == 3) %>%
   summarise(value = sum(value))
```